# ChainId conflict between localhost and hardhat: Error HH101: Hardhat was set to use chain id 1337, but connected to a chain with id 31337

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am running into an error where I want to connect to my localhost to deploy a script on the localhost chain but hardhat-config doesn't recognize localhost as the same chain as hardhat.

Relevant section of `hardhat-config.js`:

```
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    //url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
      chainId: 31337,
      blockConfirmations: 1,
      forking: {
        url: MAINNET_RPC_URL,
      },
    },
    localhost: {
      chainId: 1337 || 31337,
      blockConfirmations: 1,
    },
  },
```

Hardhat command I attempt:

`$ hh deploy --network localhost --tags 99`

And the error that pops up:

`Error HH101: Hardhat was set to use chain id 1337, but connected to a chain with id 31337.`

Is there a way to resolve this conflict? I want **localhost** to be set to `1337` yet **hardhat** seems to gain priority on it despite being set `31337`

Comment: I suppose that you started a custom hardhat node with `hardhat node` right ?

Comment: Yes I indeed spun up a node with "hh node" (same command I assume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so as per your comment you do have a standalone hardhat network started with :

```
hh node
```

Which will default in the network setup on `127.0.0.1:8545` with `chainId` : 31337

You can maintain several configuration files like so :

`hardhat.config.js` :

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

const MAINNET_RPC_URL = "http://YOUR-RPC_URL";

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      blockConfirmations: 1,
      forking: {
        url: MAINNET_RPC_URL,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And `localhost.config.js` :

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
      blockConfirmations: 1,
    },
  },
};
```

Then, just run your node using `hh --config localhost.config.js node` and the configuration from `localhost.config.js` will be picked up, setting up the network with a `chainId` of 1337. You can customize the url and port if needed.

If you have a lot of overlap between the configurations, maybe using an environment variable is the best solution to switch between hardhat network configurations, but that will depend on your project and personal preferences.

Finally, you can also keep the `localhost` network in the `hardhat.config.js` but you will need to provide the appropriate url `http://127.0.0.1:8545/` under the `localhost` network configuration. That way you can run all your scripts on the embedded hardhat network or add the `--network localhost` option to switch to your local standalone hardhat node.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm so sorry, can you provide an example template of how exactly to format hardhat.config.json or localhost.config.json? 

I wrapped them in brackets and still got an error trying that command.

Comment: I edited the answer with the actual content of the respective files if that can make things clearer for you. Don't forget to set your actual `MAINNET_RPC_URL` and not the dummy one I included for `hardhat.config.json`

Comment: I got stumped because I thought you meant to set the file names as `hardhat.config.json` and `localhost.config.json`.  I then experimented and tacked on a .js and that's when it dawned on me you meant `hardhat.config.js`(or maybe hardhat.config.json.js)  and `localhost.config.js` and those are literally configuration files just like the default one you have to make and use for typical deployments, except you can create a configuration file specifically for a chain you want to deploy to. I apologize for asking such a silly question now but thank you so much for being so thorough.

Comment: Oh god sorry, I did write json everywhere... I edited the answer for `.js` as it should be, no need to apologize it was clearly my fault.